# Adding hostalias to jenkins agent

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I have Jenkins installed with helm.
I want to add hostalias to this Jenkins agent.
There is no corresponding method in the official documentation.
Do you know how?

```
additionalAgents:
  builkit:
    podName: buildkit
    customJenkinsLabels: buildkit
    image: "harbor.local.com/plus/jenkins/agent-buildkit"
    tag: "1.0"
    alwaysPullImage: true
```

For example, I want to add the host of '10.10.250.160 harbor.local.com' to the agent above.